# Does Robotium Recorder records action done in Real device?

Tags: android, automation, robotium

I am not able to record any action done in real device

Only when I use the emulator the system records actions.

How to do I automate actions done in Real device.

The problem with the emulator is the system is not recording inputs given through the manual keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

Robotium recorder works works properly in real devices. 
If it is checked carefully using robotium, then better o/p possible.
Moreover, now Robotium recorder works for Android Studio effectively.
Thanks~

Answer (score 0):

Robotium Recorder works on both physical devices and emulators. Check if your phone has external storage (SD-card) as that is needed.